# List get item causing error when I use operator[]

Tags: python, c++, list, boost

I use boost 1.57 and boost python. Here is my code example:

```
list records = call_method<list>(...);
object attr = records.attr("__len__")();
int n = extract<long>(attr);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    records[i];
}//here cause error
```

In this list I have stored some tuples containing strings from Python. It seems that `records[i]` out of this scope will call `Py_DECREF` and cause an error, so what should I do to get data from item?

Comment: What is `records[i];` supposed to do? What is `list`? I assume not a `std::list` since that doesn't have random access. What is the error?

Comment: `list` is the boost::python::list. First I used `boost::python::call_method<std::list<std::tuple<std::string,std::string> > >(...)` to get result but cause program crash. Then I found it should use `boost::python::list` to retain the result. But also if I write `boost::python::object obj=records[i]` get crash on `Py_DECREF` in `~object_base()` when it run out of loop scope. So how should I do correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some operator[] may cause these phenomenon, so I have to avoid it and use following solution:

```
#include <boost/python/stl_iterator.hpp>

        list records = call_method<list>(...);
        stl_input_iterator<tuple> end;
        for (stl_input_iterator<tuple> itr(records); itr != end;++itr)
        {
            auto record = *itr;
            std::string tick = call_method<std::string>(record.ptr(), "__getitem__", 0);
            ...
        }
```